# using replaceWith on all child inputs JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically on .show() I've been trying to have all of the inputs convert to image tags with the img src equaling the original inputs value like this:

```
var currentPage = $('.three_paj_els:visible');
var nextPage = currentPage.next('.three_paj_els');
var the_parent_div_id = currentPage.attr('id');
    nextPage.show(function() {
        $('div#' + the_parent_div_id + ':input').each(function() {
            var the_image_SRC = $(this).val();
            $(this).replaceWith('<img src="' + the_image_SRC + '" ')
        })
    })
```

Been at it for a few hours now. I want only the ones in that specific div that gets shown to convert.

here's a fiddle of what I've been working on http://jsfiddle.net/Utr6v/100/ 
when you click the next button, the  `<input type="hidden" />` tags should convert to `<img>` tags and the images should show.

Thanks a bunch in advance.
-Sal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentPage` doesn't seem to have an ID. But you're overcomplicating it - if you have the element, you can use that to execute jQuery functions on. You don't need to do an element -> ID -> element conversion since that's pointless.

To find descendants you need to put a space between the element selector and the descendant selector, otherwise the selector applies to the elements themselves. In your case, you can just use `.find`.

Also, you were missing the closing tag of the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/Utr6v/101/

```
// I guess you want to replace with images on the new page, not the one
// which gets hidden

nextPage.find(':input').each(function() {
    var the_image_SRC = $(this).val();
    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="' + the_image_SRC + '">')
});
```

Comment: I can accept the answer in two minutes and damn that was much easier than I thought it had to be